# best way to separate and align header and paragraph elements

Tags: css, xhtml, format

I am trying to create an xhtml section like below. Profile is a 'h2' element and the paragraph on the right is a 'p' element. I want to keep the 'p' text from wrapping below Profile.

***What I want it to look like***

```
_________________________________________________________________

Profile    '        paragraph goes here...some text some text
                    some text some text. this text will stay in 
                    its own section and not wrap around Profile!
_________________________________________________________________
```

***What it actually looks like***

```
_________________________________________________________________

Profile    '        paragraph goes here...some text some text
                    some text some text. this text will stay in 
its own section and not wrap around Profile!
_________________________________________________________________
```

Below is the code I currently have.

***xhtml***

```
  <div class="section">
          <h2>Profile</h2>
          <p>This will have some information in it!</p>
  </div>
```

***css***

```
 .section {border-bottom: 1px solid #0000A0;}
 .section h2{ float:left; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em;  }
```

I have tried many approaches but this one seems to be the closest. Please let me know if I am going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your P element, apply overflow:hidden. Text will remain in the p container without overfloding under the h2 element.

**Your css**

```
.section {border-bottom: 1px solid #0000A0;}
.section h2{ float:left; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em;}
.section p{overflow:hidden;} /* addded this line */
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I'll accept your answer but need to wait 7 more minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Charming is cool  ;) By the way, your question is nicely formated and clear. Keep it up this way and you'll always find your answers.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div class="section">
      <h2>Profile</h2>

         <p> paragraph goes here...some text some text
                    some text some text. this text will stay in 
             its own section and not wrap around Profile!
       paragraph goes here...some text some text
                    some text some text. this text will stay in 
             its own section and not wrap around Profile!</p>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .section {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #0000A0;}
 .section h2{ float:left; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em;  }
.section p
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/WPgt9/25/

Answer (score 0):

You need to `float` the paragraph too, and apply `overflow:hidden` to `section` tag. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2Kge/